# Replace value in column by previous value having pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

Let's say we have data frame `x` defined as

```
x <- data.frame(a = c('Start : 20220101', '1', '1', '1', 'Start : 20220102', '2', '2', 'Start : 20220103', '3', '3'),
           b = c(NA, 200, 200, 200, NA, 200, 200, NA, 200, 200),
           c = c(NA, 1, 3, 5, NA, 2, 4, NA, 3, 5))

                  a   b  c
1  Start : 20220101  NA NA
2                 1 200  1
3                 1 200  3
4                 1 200  5
5  Start : 20220102  NA NA
6                 2 200  2
7                 2 200  4
8  Start : 20220103  NA NA
9                 3 200  3
10                3 200  5
```

I need to replace column `a`'s value by previous `Start : ...`'s `...` which indicates it's full date.

My desired output might make by problem more clear.

```
         a     b     c
1 20220101   200     1
2 20220101   200     3
3 20220101   200     5
4 20220102   200     2
5 20220102   200     4
6 20220103   200     3
7 20220103   200     5
```

Data `x` always have patern with `Start : YMD` and `D` follows.

Original `x` have more than `10^8` rows, so I think it need to be very efficient.

Any help would be grateful.

What I tried is

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(readr)

x %>%
  mutate(d = floor((rleid(a)+1)/2))  %>%
  group_by(d) %>%
  mutate(a = first(parse_number(a))) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-d)
```

Comment: Is it always the same number of rows between the `Start` rows or does it vary?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I apologize for confusing example. It's different every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one `data.table` solution with `zoo::na.locf` to fill `NA` values.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)
#Change all the a values to NA except the ones that start with "Start"
x[, a := replace(a, !grepl('^Start', a), NA)]
#Remove "Start" from a so only the date remains. 
x[, a := sub('Start\\s*:\\s*', '', a)]
#Replace NA with latest non-NA values.
zoo::na.locf(x)

#          a   b c
#1: 20220101 200 1
#2: 20220101 200 3
#3: 20220102 200 3
#4: 20220102 200 2
#5: 20220102 200 4
#6: 20220103 200 4
#7: 20220103 200 3
```

A `tidyverse` solution for the same would be -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  mutate(a = replace(a, !grepl('^Start', a), NA)) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  mutate(a = sub('Start\\s*:\\s*', '', a))
```

Comment: Thank you for quick, efficient solution! Have a nice day :)